# SwiftUI - View not updating after adding linked object in Coredata

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a SwiftUI view called `InstanceView`, which shows the details of an `Instance` from a `NagivationView`. The links in the `NavigationView` are objects from Coredata called `Instance`s, and also in Coredata, I have an entity called `Solve`. `Instance` has a one-to-many relationship with `Solve`. `InstanceView` displays a list of the `Solve`s linked to it.

My problem is that when I create a new `Solve`, and add it to an `Instance`, from my `InstanceView`, the new solve doesn't appear in the `InstanceView` until I select a different `Instance` in the `NavigationView`, and return to the original `Instance`.

Here is the `List` inside the `NavigationView` that controls which `Instance` is shown in the `InstanceView`:

```
List {
    ForEach(Array(zip(instances.indices, instances)), id: \.0) { index, instance in
        NavigationLink(destination: InstanceView(instance: instance), tag: index, selection: $selectedInstanceIndex) {
            InstanceRow(instance: instance)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `InstanceView`:

```
struct InstanceView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    var instance: Instance
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(instance.solveArray, id: \.self) { solve in
                Text(String(solve.time))
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(instance.wrappedName)
        .navigationSubtitle(instance.wrappedPuzzle)
        
        Button("add solve") {
            addSolve()
        }
        
    }
    
    private func addSolve() {
        withAnimation {
            let newSolve = Solve(context: viewContext)
            newSolve.time = 3.2
            newSolve.dnf = false
            newSolve.plusTwo = false
            newSolve.timestamp = Date()

            instance.addToSolve(newSolve)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I was wondering how I could force the `InstanceView` to update so that it shows the new `Solve` added from inside it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and figured I would post my solution in case anyone else had the same problem. I was able to solve this just by adding `@ObservedObject` in front of `var instance: Instance`.

Answer (score 0):

try using this in "InstanceView":

```
@State var instance: Instance
```

or

```
@Binding var instance: Instance
```

If that does not work your best bet is to make "Instance" a class and ObservableObject and do it that way.

Comment: State and Binding didn't work unfortunately. I'd like to try to use ObservableObject but I'm not sure how I do that with a class from Coredata. This is my Instance Class: https://pastebin.com/20hTjMFy. I think NSManagedObject already conforms to ObservableObject? But I'm not sure where to go from there.